# trying to make long self sizing cell using UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

So I have a pretty simple layout, with self sizing cell (something like tags), get it working using UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout and estimated item width, but as soon as I get a long string that doesn't fit in collection view, I get an error: "UICollectionView internal inconsistency: missing final attributes for cell".

```
class FruitViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    let data: [String] = [
//        "Apple",
        "Apple, Apple Apple Apple Apple Apple Apple Apple Apple Apple",
        "Pear",
        "Orange",
        "Fig",
        "Carrot",
        "Cabbage",
        "Potato",
        "Pear",
    ]
    
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (sectionIndex, _) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: .init(
            widthDimension: .estimated(10),
            heightDimension: .absolute(36))
        )
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
            heightDimension: .estimated(10)
        )
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(
            layoutSize: groupSize,
            subitems: [item]
        )
        group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(8)
        
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.interGroupSpacing = 8
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 16, bottom: 16, trailing: 16)
        
        return section
    }
    
    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.register(MyCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "id")
        
        return collectionView
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "id", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        cell.myLabel.text = data[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
}

class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let myLabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        contentView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        contentView.addSubview(myLabel)
        myLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            myLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            myLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            myLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8),
            myLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8)
        ])
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to get line break for label ones it gets too long?

Comment: You ever figure this out? Even truncating would be fine for me.

Comment: i'm having this same problem too with tag style layout...app crashes if text is too long. .i'm also fine with truncating but can't get that to work either. what did you guys end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

You can give your cell a width less-than-or-equal-to constraint. In the code, set the constant to the width of your collection view minus any content insets that you may have.

Comment: Could you share code, please?